# Which is better? XML, INI, or something else?

Tags: c, xml, ini

I'm writing a program in C, and I am going to need a configuration file.  Problem is, I don't know which would be better.  This program is looking to get pretty huge, with several parts all trying to get information from the same config file.  So does anybody have any suggestions on which is better?  OR maybe something I never thought about?

Comment: We cannot tell you, since your question is too vague. What will be in the configuration file? Are you on a particular platform? On Windows the registry is good for simple configurations.

Comment: Will the config file need to be manually edited? or will it be a repository for persisting system values?

Comment: It can be manually edited, but I do plan on building a small GUI to edit the values.  Perhaps I should have cleared this up.  It's going to be on *nix systems.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sqlite](http://sqlite.org), really.

Answer (score 1):

There are some dedicated *configuration file* libraries, e.g.

- http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/

> - A fully reentrant parser. Independent configurations can be parsed in concurrent threads at the same time.
> - Both C and C++ bindings, as well as hooks to allow for the creation of wrappers in other languages.
> - A simple, structured configuration file format that is more readable and compact than XML and more flexible than the obsolete but prevalent Windows “INI” file format.
> - A low-footprint implementation (just 37K for the C library and 76K for the C++ library) that is suitable for memory-constrained systems.
> - Proper documentation.

Example configuration file: http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/test.cfg.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'd use XML :

- Simple manual editing.
- In the future, you'd have the possibility to write a model to validate your configuration file (with DTD, XSD, RNG or Schematron).
- Easy to parse with any langage.

Comment: I'd give a +1 for the validation aspect, but a -1 for *simple* editing.

Comment: I agree, XML isn't the simpliest way, perhaps I should have just said 'Manual editing' ;)